# Update subdocument with mongodb and php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this document:

```
places: {
'name': 'wallmart',
'categories' : [{'name':'store','accuracy':'1'}]
}
```

A place can have a lot of categories, each with a different value.

In certain situations, the value of a category can rise.

Im trying to update but its not working, it changes the document and becomes like this:

```
{...
'categories' : {'name':'store','accuracy':'2'}
...}
```

It removes the array and add just one subdocument.

This is my php code:

```
                $query = array('_id'=>$place['_id']);
                $acc = $place_cat['accuracy'] + 1;
                $params = array('$set' => array("categories" => array('name'=>$cat['name'],'accuracy'=>$acc)));
                $col->update($query,$params);
```

Which is the correct update sintax?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$col->update(array('_id'=>$place['_id'], 'categories.name'=>'store'), 
    array('$inc' => array('categories.$.accuracy'=>1)))
```

Will do what you want, atomically as well.

Comment: @leojg NP, the operations used are dot notation and the positional operator to reach into the subdocuments if you wanna read into it more